# invocación del fetch devuelve "undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, rest, promesas, fetch

Buen día! recientemente inicié un pequeño proyecto, busco consumir una API REST y para ello utilizo Fetch() lo curioso del caso es que me devuelve "undefined" creí que utilizando Async/await podría solucionar eso pero no fue asi

```
    path(URI){
    console.log("esta corriendo path")
    let datadata =[];
    const request = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(URI);
          const json = await response.json();
          for(let i=0; i<json.length;i++){
            datadata[i] = json[i];
            console.log("awebo");
          }      
        }
        catch(error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      }

request();
return datadata;

} //cierre de path `
```

y al a hora de que lo invoco me da el undefined pero si agrego un stTimeout lo soluciono, mi duda es, es la forma mas optima de trabajarlo? necesito extraer el json y que viene de la URI y usarlo en otros metodos que no son asincronos

```
  let algo = this.path('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("esperando 0.5seg")
        console.log(algo[1]["name"]);
        //probalmente todo el codigo deba ir aqui y no deseo eso
    },500)
```

Existe otra manera de extraer el json y manipularlo a mi gusto en otras funciones?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este código

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


export const useFetch =  (url) => {
    const [estado,setEstado]=useState({
        data: [],
        loading: true
    });

    useEffect( () => {
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then( (dataResultante) => setEstado({
            loading: false,
            data: dataResultante} ) )
        .catch(error => console.error('Error en el URL:', error));

    }, [url]);

    return estado;
```

}

Con el fetch(url) tomas el código que viene de la URI y, con los hooks useState + useEffect manipulas el resultado....

Comment: ¡Saludos! Muchas gracias por contribuir a Stack Overflow. La respuesta seguramente funcione, pero, ¿por qué lo hace? ¿Qué has añadido? Deberías añadir esa información para que el OP pueda saber qué mejorar. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Como te han indicado, pulsa en [edit] para explicar en tu respuesta cómo funciona este código. Ten siempre presente que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.